# Passing variable to external PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I'm having a (probably super simple) issue. The code below is supposed to _POST (using AJAX) a variable called 'id' to an external file called getYourData.php.

I think the issue is below. The 'data' section doen't seem to be functioning - I've even tried putting [data: '2'] to simply put '2' in the SELECT statement. But that doesn't even work.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getYourData.php',
        data: 'id',
        success: function(msg){
            //everything echoed in your PHP-File will be in the 'msg' variable:
            $('#selectTwo').html(msg)
            $('#selectTwo').fadeIn(500);
        }
});
```

**Here's the rest of code** (snippet - jquery has been imported)

```
<!-- First Box: click on link shows up second box -->
<div id="selectOne" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px; border: #666 thin solid; padding: 10px;">
  <a href="#" id="1">One</a><br />
  <a href="#" id="2">Two</a><br />
  <a href="#" id="3">Three</a>
</div>

<!-- Second Box: initially hidden with CSS "display: none;" -->
<div id="selectTwo" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px; display: none; border: #666 thin solid; padding: 10px;"></div>

<!-- The JavaScript (jQuery) -->
<script type="text/javascript">

//Do something when the DOM is ready:
$(document).ready(function() {

//When a link in div with id "selectOne" is clicked, do something:
$('#selectOne a').click(function() {
    //Fade in second box:
    $('#selectTwo').fadeIn(500);

    //Get id from clicked link:
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getYourData.php',
        data: '2',
        success: function(msg){
            //everything echoed in your PHP-File will be in the 'msg' variable:
            $('#selectTwo').html(msg)
            $('#selectTwo').fadeIn(500);
        }
});

    //Depending on the id of the link, do something:
    if (id == 'one') {
        //Insert html into the second box which was faded in before:
        $('#selectTwo').html('One<br />is<br />selected')
    } else if (id == 'two') {
        $('#selectTwo').html('Two<br />is<br />selected')
    } else if (id == 'three') {
        $('#selectTwo').html('Three<br />is<br />selected')
    }

    });


});
</script>
```

**getYourData.php** - creates a custom SELECT statement based on the 'id' passed from primary page. For some reason, this isn't working. Only works when I intentionally set a dud variable ($id2)

```
<?php


$username="primary";
$password="testpass";
$database="testdb";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password) or die ('Unable to connect...');

mysql_select_db($database) or die('Error: '.mysql_error ());

//Intentionally creating a dud variable will create a good SELECT statement and work
$id2 = "3";

$id = $_POST['id'];
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id='.$id);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

//Now echo the results - they will be in the callback variable:
echo $result['firstname'].', '.$result['lastname'];

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: `data` in your AJAX function needs to be of the form 'id=xxx'. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Andrew: but it's a variable... it changes depending on what id (link) the user clicks. What would xxx be?

Comment: @Zakman441: I see you have it in the variable `id`. Try `'id=' + id`. Confusing I know lol

Comment: @Andrew: Can you post that as an answer? That worked perfectly. Doesn't make any sense to me why you have to do that though lol. Thank you! Please post an answer so I can select it?

Comment: @Zakman411: Because you're forming a string. jQuery does not automagically parse your string and do variable lookup for you, because this would be _far_ too restrictive. Consider when your HTTP parameter does not have the same name as your variable, or when the data comes from something more complex than some simple variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` in your AJAX function needs to be of the form 'id=xxx'. I see you have it in the variable id. Try `data: 'id=' + id`. Confusing I know.

The explanation here is that POST data should be of the form `a=b,c=d,...` et cetera. That way PHP will pick it up as a key/value pair in the $_POST dictionary. Now you have a variable `id` which you would like to send (value), and you also want this to be the name of the (key). Hence you would need to do `data: 'id=' + id`. If `id=2`, then that will evaluate to `data: 'id=2'`, which is correct.

Ultimately, as @Stephen noted, it is better to use an Object for the data field, as it is arguably more elegant. `data: {'id': id}` should work as well, and you can add more variables in the future.

Comment: But if he needs to add more data in the future, he'll continually have this messy string to work with.. You're much better off using an object..

Comment: I completely agree with you @Stephen, I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried data: {id: 2 } - object, not an array.

Comment: That actually worked! BUT, I need the id variable to be transmitted, not the '2'. Is there a way to just do data: {id}? That throws an error for me..

Comment: data: { 'id': $(this).attr('id') }

Comment: Also, you've already put it in a variable called id.. so the syntax is  alittle strange looking but  data: {'id': id }

Comment: 'id=' + id ended up working...weird haha. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: You can do that but its less than ideal.. Note - when you make an object and use 'id' - you need to put 'id' in qutotes because its a reserved word in javascript.

Comment: {'id': id} did work. You're saying that's better syntax? And you mean when I declared it? Should I pick a different variable name?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the data in your ajax call is wrong. The php references $_POST['id'] in your call but the var ID is not sent.

from : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> dataObject, String
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
>   (described below).

Should be more like this:

data: "id=2",

Comment: That works, but only returns member_id of 2. How can I send the 'id' variable that changes based on user input?